# Program gets stuck when importing theano in Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, theano

```
root@ubuntubraintech:~/wwj# /home/braintech/anaconda2/bin/python
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import numpy
>>> import scipy
>>> import theano
```

After importing the theano module, the program just gets stuck there, displaying nothing, even after quite a long time. Could anyone give me a hand?

Comment: OK, Let me explain the reason. The bug occurs because of disconnection to the Internet, the original version of Theano is 0.7, it attempts to update to its latest version, thus it just gets stuck there, and I try to connect to the Internet, then the problem is resolved.

Comment: Sorry, after a thorough bug-checking process, I find that my driver for GPU failed when initializing, that makes the mysterious problem, reinstalling the GPU driver, and I fixed it.